# React Navigation redux navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I'd like to know how the navigation supposed to happen, when redux stores the navigation state.

**Short version:**

If the redux store isn't in initial state, a screen is mounted without actually navigationg there.

**Detailed description:**

Now I'm able to navigate either by (1) using the navigation props given by the parent navigator *(StackNavigator in my case)* or by (2) dispatching an action.

1: `this.props.navigation.navigate('main')`

2: `this.props.navigateToMainAction()`

The reducer:

```
const INIT_STATE = Nav.router.getStateForAction(
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'login' })
);
const navReducer = (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
    const newState = Nav.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    return newState || state;
};
```

Nav structure:

```
const authStack = StackNavigator({
    login: { screen: LoginScreen }
    ,forgottendPassword: { screen: LoginScreen }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'login'
    ,headerMode: 'none'
});

const homeDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
    home: {
        screen: HomeScreen
        ,navigationOptions: { drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed' }
    }
}, {
    drawerPosition: 'right'
    ,drawerWidth: 300
    ,contentComponent: props => <HomeDrawerMenu {...props} />
});

const mainStack = StackNavigator({
    homeDrawer: {
        screen: homeDrawer
        ,navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            header: <HomeMenu navigate={navigation.navigate} />
        })
    }
    ,partnerList: {
        screen: PartnerListScreen
        ,navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            header: <PartnerListMenu navigation={navigation} />
        })
    }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'homeDrawer'
});

const Nav = StackNavigator({
    auth: { screen: authStack }
    ,main: { screen: mainStack }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'auth',
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

When I try to navigate from `auth/login` to `main` and from there to `main/partnerList` it only works correctly, if the redux store is in initial state *(after I cleared the async storage)*.

But when I reload the app, it mounts the `main/partnerList` component, without actually navigating there and thanks to that, the action which fetching the partnerList comp.'s data is also called.

Expected action order on load:

```
@@INIT
Offline/STATUS_CHANGED
persist/REHYDRATE
check_token <- Check if the user is logged in (in this case he is)
check_token_commit
Navigation/NAVIGATE <- The user is forwarded to main, when he is logged in
Navigation/NAVIGATE <- The user goes to the partnerList component
fetch_partner_list <- Action for fetching the partner list
Offline/BUSY
fetch_partner_list_commit
```

Current action order on load:

```
@@INIT
Offline/STATUS_CHANGED
persist/REHYDRATE
check_token <- Check if the user is logged in (in this case he is)
fetch_partner_list <- It's already fetching, but no navigate action was triggered yet
Offline/BUSY
check_token_commit
Navigation/NAVIGATE <- The user is forwarded to main, when he is logged in
Navigation/NAVIGATE <- The forwarding happens twice, for some reason
fetch_partner_list_commit
Navigation/NAVIGATE <- The user goes to the partnerList component
fetch_partner_list <- The only time it should be triggered
Offline/BUSY
fetch_partner_list_commit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was coused by the inappropriate use of the react navigation.

I had to wrap the auth and main router and pass down in screenProps the root navigation object.